# What's the difference between the normal Mac Mini and Mac Mini Server?

Tags: mac, mac-mini, server.app

I'm planning to buy a Mac mini i5 as it's fitting my budget. 
Will be making it a server for hosting websites, so before I buy the i5 version I wanted to know if there is any hardware difference between the mini & mini server.
Hardware difference as in working of the motherboard or any thing added extra.

**i will be upgrading the mini with 16GB RAM & an SSD**

Answer (score 1):

There is no Mac Mini Server with an i5 processor, and with your upgrades, the Mac Mini with OS X Server has no hardware differences from the normal i7 Mac Mini. Unless you want 2 internal SSDs, you would be wasting $200. I assume that if you're hosting other websites then you would be using external Thunderbolt or USB drives for storage space, so it would make sense just to have the 256GB SSD.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I'm getting a good deal on the i5 Mac mini. I want to use it to host one pager websites. I already have a 250GB Samsung EVO SSD. I'm planning on using Mavericks + the server app. Good idea? Let me know what you think about it.  I'm just confused between the "Mac mini server" & "Mac mini". Btw I really don't care about i5 or i7. They really don't make any different interms of hosting websites.

Comment: @Abhilash The Mac mini server is just a relic from the times where OS X Server was a separate, and expensive, OS and not just an app on the App Store. It came with OS X Server and had more storage space, but now there is not much of a difference. I don't know why it still exists. I would personally not recommend using OS X Server. Instead, try [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/) or just manage your server from the command line.